# Laravel - query builder - sort results by amount of tags

Tags: php, laravel, tags

I have query designed like that:

```
 $tags = auth()->user()->tags->toArray();
    return $this->posts($request)->whereHas('tags', function ($q) use ($tags) {
      $q->where(function ($q) use ($tags) {
        foreach ($tags as $tag) {
          $q->orWhere('tags.tag', 'like', $tag["tag"]);
        }
      })->select(DB::raw('count(distinct tags.id)'));
    })->paginate(perPage());
```

The SQL can be:

```
select * from `posts` 
where `posts`.`deleted_at` is null 
and `expire_at` >= '2017-03-26 21:23:42.000000' 
and (
select count(distinct tags.id) from `tags` 
inner join `post_tag` on `tags`.`id` = `post_tag`.`tag_id` 
where `post_tag`.`post_id` = `posts`.`id` 
and (`tags`.`tag` like 'PHP' or `tags`.`tag` like 'pop' or `tags`.`tag` like 'UI')
) >= 1
```

But I need order the results by number of tags in posts, then should be something like that:

```
select p.*
from posts p
join (
select pt.post_id,
    count(distinct t.id) as tag_count
from tags t
inner join post_tag pt on t.id = pt.tag_id
where t.tag in ('PHP', 'pop', 'UI')
group by pt.post_id
) pt on p.id = pt.post_id
where p.deleted_at is null
and p.expire_at >= '2017-03-26 21:23:42.000000'
order by pt.tag_count desc;
```

Is it possible create it in Laravel? How can be the query done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`withCount()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models) method:

```
->withCount(['tags' => function($q) {
    q->where.... // Put conditionals here if needed.
}])
->orderBy('tags_count', 'desc')
```

> If you want to count the number of results from a relationship without actually loading them you may use the `withCount` method, which will place a `{relation}_count` column on your resulting models